# Snowflake ODBC Connection Column Limit Error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

We are connecting to Snowflake via an ODBC connection. If I query 3 columns then the query executes. If I query any extra columns I get the following error?

```
ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (25) 
  Result download worker error: Worker error: [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
  REST request for URL https://sfc-ie-ds1-7-customer-stage.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/I've removed rest of URL for security reasons failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=35 msg='SSL connect error' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

- you probably have a proxy that hasn't whitelisted the connection to the Snowflake account internal stage (identified by URL https://sfc-ie-ds1-7-customer-stage.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com).

Long version:

- every time a query returns a result set larger than 100 KB in size, it is stored on an internal stage of your Snowflake account and the driver is instructed to download the result from there. This means driver will connect directly to a stage URL.
- if you have an SSL proxy in your network this usually means the certificates will be changed and Snowflake doesn't support that therefore the connection will be refused. Whitelisting all Snowflake URLs at proxy level resolves the problem.

To diagnose the issue properly you can install [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd) by following the steps from documentation and when run it should show you the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why does it work for a smaller amount of columns then though? Surely all queries would fail? Or do you think it's linked to the 100 kb limit?

Comment: It should be linked to the 100KB size of the resultset. How many rows are you retrieving? Even with 3 columns if you would retrieve more than a few thousands of rows I would expect same issue.

Comment: So there's 1058 rows there at the minute?

Comment: It all depends on the data type of the 3 columns and if those 1000 rows are below 100KB with 3 columns only.